# paramiko and sudo su - oracle

Tags: sudo, paramiko

I am trying to connect to a linux server using test user and executing a command sudo su - oracle whoami. But cannot do it correctly.
Can anyone helpme on this?

My code is as follows

```
import paramiko as pk
import socket as sk
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt

class Master:
    client = None
    error = None
    host = None
    user = None
    passwd = No

def __init__(self, address, username, password=None):
    self.client = pk.SSHClient()
    self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(pk.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, port=22, timeout=2)
        self.host = address
        self.user = username
        self.passwd = password

    except pk.SSHException as e:
        self.error = e
    except sk.timeout:
        self.error = "Socket timedout"
    except:
        self.error = "Unknown Error"

def sendCommand(self, command, pty=False):
    out = []
    print("\nCommand that is passed is {}".format(command))
    if(self.client):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command, get_pty=pty, timeout=5)
        print(stderr.readlines())
        for line in stdout.readlines():
            out.append(line.strip())
        return out
    else:
        print("Connection not opened.")


host = '10.1.1.50'
user = 'test'
password = 'abc123'

conn = Master(address=host, username=user, password=password)

command = "echo -e {} | sudo su - oracle whoami \n".format(password)
output = conn.sendCommand(command, pty=True)

print(output)
```

Can anyone suggest how to sudo su - oracle using paramiko?

Answer (score 0):

use fabric to achieve this -

```
from fabric.api import env, sudo, run
env.password="LOCALUSERPASSWORD"
run("echo 'whoami' | sudo su - oracle")#Prints oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that *exec_command* creates a **new channel** everytime you use it. Instead we can *invoke_shell* which will return a channel object.

```
import paramiko
import time

host = "myserver.com"
username = "user"
password = "pass"
port = "22"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)

commands = ['sudo su - oracle', 'mkdir foo']

channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

time.sleep(1) 
channel.recv(9999)
channel.send("\n")
time.sleep(1)

for command in commands:
    channel.send(command + "\n")
    while not channel.recv_ready(): 
        time.sleep(0.1)
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    output = channel.recv(9999) 
    print(output.decode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0.1)
channel.close()
```

- You can pass a list of commands as shown above
- [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67528539/login-as-different-user-to-run-commands-using-paramiko/71166446#71166446)